# Not able to connect ArgoCD with GitLab repository

Tags: gitlab, argocd

I am getting following error while trying to add repository using HTTPS in ArgoCD from GitLab.

Unable to connect HTTPS repository: all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 10.100.20.235:8081: connect: connection refused"

Comment: It looks like when Argo is running a job, it's attempting to connect to GitLab, but cannot reach the IP address given. A 10.* IP address is a private IP address, so I assume you're running your own GitLab cluster. You should work with your network team to ensure that the GitLab IP is routable from wherever argo is being hosted.